# Formatting Cobol Output into a table

Tags: formatting, cobol

I need to create a program that takes user input and displays answers in a table.

I have most of it done, im just unsure how to create columns and rows, along with their respectable titles inside the data file.

I've been unable to find a tutorial and I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Tl'dr
If I want to turn

```
Box   14    14.99
Square 11   12.99
Cube   09   09.99
```

Into

```
___________________________________
|Item  |   Item Count  | Item Price|
| Box  |       14      |    14.99  |
|Square|       11      |    12.99  |
|Cube  |       09      |    09.99  |
```

How would i go about doing it?

Tutorial / explanation preferred and appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You setup an output record like

```
 01  Output-Rec.
     03                    pic X value '|'.
     03 Item               pic x(5).
     03                    pic x value '|'.
     03 Item-Count         pic ---,---.--9.
....

+ header's etc
```

And you read the input file and move the values from the input record to the output record.

Alternately if your compiler supports the Report-Writer, you can lookup the Cobol-Report writer. Try Google